# How to use "FLAGS" (command line switches) in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to set custom batch size in my application.

If I put the following code into my app

```
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 128,
                            """Number of images to process in a batch.""")
```

it says the following error

```
argparse.ArgumentError: argument --batch_size: conflicting option string(s): --batch_size
```

and if I remove this statement, it swears:

```
usage: <myscript> [-h] [--batch_size BATCH_SIZE] [--data_dir DATA_DIR]
                      [--checkpoint_dir CHECKPOINT_DIR]
```

at the line where `FLAGS.batch_size` used.

`myscript` is the name of my script and I didn't write this message anywhere and don't expect these command line switches at all. Looks like `TF` uses some Python switch parsing library and expecting these switches somehow. How to avoid this and expect custom switches?

How to hardcode custom batch_size?

**UPDATE**

My command line is follows:

```
myscript image1.png image2.png image3.png
```

PNGs are images from CIFAR database I wish to recognize from command line. This is command line I wish it to be, I don't wish it contain options listed in "usage" output.

Comment: Can you please add command line that you use to run your script?

Comment: A list of image PNG files I wish to process. This is what I want, I don't want  `batch_size` be set from command line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From your update, it sounds like you don't want to use the `FLAGS` module at all. If you look at a program like `cifar10_train.py`, you'll see the following [near the bottom of the script](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e008ecf12607f691952a9bfe8971f406b30bc56e/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py#L129):

```
def main(argv=None):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
  # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

The [`tf.app.run()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e008ecf12607f691952a9bfe8971f406b30bc56e/tensorflow/python/platform/default/_app.py) invocation is a bit of boilerplate that ensures that any flags are parsed, and then invokes the `main()` function in the same module. Notice that `main()` has an `argv` argument. This will be filled with the remaining arguments to your program: in your example, it will be a list `["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png"]`. Therefore you can simply write your `main()` function to be something like:

```
def main(argv=None):
  if argv:
    for filename in argv:
      run_inference_on_file(filename)
```

Comment: why does TensorFlow have a flags wrapper/library if python already has one that works fine?

Comment: Is there anywhere in the documentation that FLAGS is covered?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are importing [cifar10.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10.py) that already has the `batch_size` flag defined, and the error is due to you trying to re-define a flag with the same name. If you are importing `cifar10`, you can simply use `--batch_size` from the command line, and `FLAGS.batch_size` in your code.